# How to merge two different HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i merge 1 table with another table from other page?

I basicly having 3 radio buttons.

My intention is when first i tick A,then it will show website A and next while ticking B...i shall be able to view website A too...So after thinking B...i will see website A on my left & website B on my right.

But my code below could not work as i expected...it will juz display the content of the last radio button i tick.

Kindly assist.TQ

```
<!DOC HTML>
<HTML>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

<!--
function show(id)
{
 if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none')
 {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
 }
}
//-->

<!--
function hide(id)
{
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';

}
//-->
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<table cellspacing="1" cols="3" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top" align="left">
  <td width="202"><b>Please, select option</b></td>

  <td width="481">A
    <input type="radio" name="Option" onfocus="hide('tblB');hide('tblC');show('tblA');">
    B
    <input type="radio" name="Option"           
onfocus="hide('tblA');hide('tblC');show('tblB');return true;">
    C      
    <input type="radio" name="Option"  
onfocus="hide('tblA');hide('tblB');show('tblC');return true;">
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


<table id="tblA" style="DISPLAY: none" cols="1" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top" align="left">

<td>
  You&nbsp;select A,
  table
  tblA is shown<frameset cols="50%,*">
<frame src="http://www.huawei.com">
</frameset>&nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="tblB" style="DISPLAY: none" cols="1" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top" align="left">
  <td>
   You&nbsp;select B, table tblB
   is shown<frameset cols="50%,*"><frame src="https://www.google.com/"></frameset>&nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="tblC" style="DISPLAY: none" cols="1" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top" align="left">
  <td>
   You&nbsp;select C, table tblC
   is shown&nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5kQA/

Comment: 1. You're using attributes like cellspacing that are now invalid (as of HTML5, which you're using). 2. You're using tables for the wrong reasons! It's for tabular data only...

Comment: Whereever you got this example code from is using practices that are *very* out of date.  `<!--` and `//-->` haven't been needed in decades.  I tend to dismiss any code that uses them automatically.  In addition, as @null pointed out, it us using archaic attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but this might help.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/eXEJe

```
<b>Please select an option</b>
A <input type="radio" name="Option" />
B <input type="radio" name="Option" />
C <input type="radio" name="Option" />

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    $('table').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).show();
});
```

---

Here's a better approach that doesn't use tables for layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/eXEJe/5

```
.frame-wrapper {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

<div id="tblA" class="frame-wrapper">
    You selected A, table tblA is shown

    <frame src="http://www.huawei.com" />
</div>

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    $('.frame-wrapper').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).show();
});
```

Comment: hmmmm..why izit upon clicking the radio buttonn...nothing shows up??

Comment: this is my header..
<HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    $('.frame-wrapper').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).fadeIn();
});
        </script>
<style type="text/css">
        .frame-wrapper {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
        </style>
</HEAD>

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to put code in comments (especially when you haven't explained why it's there). Regarding your first comment, both my fiddles work just fine. Without seeing your situation, I'm not sure how you expect me to help further.

Comment: Thk you for assisting me..I have solved my problem ;-)

Have a nice day,mates!